# Can't use ClientConfiguration

Tags: c#, couchbase

I wanted to start using `couchbase` but clientconfiguration gives an error and I cant find why, visual studio saying that it doesnt exist while I have  already installed couchbase package:

```
var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration{
    Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("http://10.112.170.101") }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have using statements for both Couchbase *and* Couchbase.Configuration.Client

Both namespaces are available in the CouchbaseNetClient nuget package.